# What is the energy in a circuit with a temperature difference and no potential difference

Tags: thermoelectricity

Suppose I have some kind of thermoelectric effect, where there is an electric current flowing from a hot to a cold electrode. If there is no bias voltage $V$ and there is a current $I$, the energy dissipated in the resistance is no longer $I^2R=VI$. What would be the heat then for this kind of systems?

Answer (score 0):

If there is both an electric current and a thermal gradient, there is a Joule effect (when the resistivity does not vanish) and a Thomson effect. The temperature distribution will be determined by the hot and cold electrodes, as well as by the Joule and Thomson heats. You must solve the corresponding heat equation to get $T(x)$.

The heat flux is given by the generalized Fourier's law: $\vec{J_Q}=ST \vec J -\kappa \nabla T$, where $\vec J$ is the current density, $S$ is the Seebeck coefficient, sigma is the conductivity, etc.

You can couple it to the generalized Ohm's law: $\vec J = -\sigma \nabla V -S\sigma \nabla T$. In your case, $\nabla V=\vec 0$, and so $\vec J =-\sigma S \nabla T$.

Edit: In response to your comment "What will be the energy drop through the resistance?", the question doesn't make as much sense as you think it does. There is an energy flux, defined at every single point in the material, it is given by $\vec {J_U}=\vec{J_Q}+\overline{\mu}\vec J$. Then, if you do the lengthy math, you'll get that there must exist a radial thermal gradient, and that the value of the energy flux is not constant throughout the material, not even radially.

Also note that imposing no voltage, $\nabla V = \vec 0$, means that you tuned the electric current such that its voltage cancels out exactly the Seebeck effect one. Is that really what you have in mind? In that case, maybe that answers your comment's question, the potential drop across the resistor is zero. The degradation of the electrostatic potential is offset by the gain in potential coming from the Seebeck effect. There is still a Joule heat though.

Comment: What will be the energy drop through the resistance?

Comment: @Mauricio I edited my answer. Let me know.

Comment: So in the case of bias voltage and no temperature difference, $\vec{J}_U=\vec{J}\Delta V$ (Joule)? And in the case of temperature difference it is something more complicated?